# Does PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry) support .tgz package coming from Artifactory for node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, manifest, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I am working on CI/CD engine and I need to deploy a node.js application into `PCF` using CI/CD engine.I am able to build and publish package in artifactory in `.tgz` format.
When I define `path: target/nodejs-app-0.0.1.tgz` in the `manifest.yml` file. I am getting an error - `/../target/...tgz has negative offset`

Can someone guild me on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cf` cli supports either a ZIP archive or a folder as the path argument to `cf push -p`. It doesn't support tgz.

From `cf push -h`:

> Path to app directory or to a zip file of the contents of the app directory

If you can bundle your app as a `.zip`, what you're trying should just work.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Let me try with .zip file